# Ruby On Rails: post method behind a file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to post a integer method behind a file in a `post` method in ruby on rails.

For this, I use `hidden_field_tag`, but it send a json to controller and I don't know how can I use this json.

I try below code:

```
<%= form_tag import_tasks_path, multipart: true do %>
    <%= file_field_tag :file %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :owner_id, :value => 1 %>
    <%= submit_tag "Import" %>
<% end %>
```

In controller, I want use file and `1` in a function:

```
Task.import(params[:file], params[:owner_id])
```

but the value of `params[:owner_id]` is: `{value=>1}`.
how can I post just value? like:

```
Task.import(params[:file], 1)
```

I try any way, but don't find solution, like:
view:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :owner_id, 1 %>
```

controller:

```
params[owner_id]
```

or:

```
params[:owner_id].dup
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be enough :

```
 <%= hidden_field_tag :owner_id, 1 %>
```

If you can't access it in your desired controller with `params[:owner_id]`, it might have a parent. Try to do a `params.inspect` in your controller, it will reveal its location.

**BONUS**

The reason it is giving `"{value=>1}"` when you give `:value => 1`, is that it gets into the hidden_field_tag's value arg as a hash, and they should be calling `to_s` on it.